# Exercise on a sequence of funcions $f_n\rightarrow f$ and Lebesgue Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, sequence-of-function

I have this sequence of functions for $n \ge 1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$
$$a_n(x)=\frac{(\sin x)^n}{x^n}$$
For first I have to find $a_n\rightarrow x$ pointwise in $(0,+\infty)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

My idea:

For $x\in (0,1)$ I have that $\sin x^n \approx x^n$ and $x^n \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$.

For $x>1$ I try to bound the sine:
$$-\frac{1}{x^n}\le\frac{(\sin x)^n}{x^n}\le\frac 1 {x^n}$$
Which clearly goes to $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

So I can say that $a_n \rightarrow x$ with $x=0$.

---

I want also compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{+\infty} a_n(x)\,dx.
$

Using the Lebesgue Dominated convergence theorem I have that $|a_n(x)|\le g(x)$ with $g(x)=0$.
So my integral is 
$$\int_0^{+\infty}|a_n(x)| \, dx=0$$

Am I right on my reasoning? Thank you.

Comment: Clearly the inequality $|x_n(x)|\le g(x)$ with $g(x)=0$is wrong (it implies that x_n(x)=0$ for all $x$.)

Comment: This inequality derives from the previous step. I think I have done something wrong. Can you see any mistake?

Comment: You've used $x$ for the function and the variable, not good.

Comment: Is $|a_{n}|\le g(x)$ with $g(x)=1/x^{n}$ a better idea? Thanks.

Comment: Fixed the bad letter assignment. Thanks.

Comment: There are two errors. (1) For $0<x<1$ you use $\sin x\sim  x$, but $a_n(x)=\sin x/x$. (2) What you say you proved is $\lim a_n(x)|\le g(x)$, not $|a_n(x)|\le g(x)$.

Comment: Is correct saying for $0<x<1$,  $a_{n}(x)=x/x=1$? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\ne0$ then $|\sin x/x|<1$; then $|a_n(x)|=|\sin x/x|^n$ converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. If $x=0$, $a_n(0)=1$, Thus, $a_n$ converges pointwise to the function defined as $a(x)=0$ if $x\ne0$, $a(0)=1$.

now, to apply the dominated convergence theorem, you need an integrable function $g$ such that $|a_n(x)|\le g(x)$. To construct this $g$ we use two obvious inequalities: $|a_n(x)|\le1$ and $a_n(x)|\le1/|x|^n$. The first one will be used for small $x$, and the second one for large $x$. With this in mind, it is not too difficult to fall upon
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if }|x|\le1,\\
\dfrac{1}{|x|^2} &\text{if }|x|>1.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your reply. With such $g(x)$ I've used the theorem, obtaining: $$\int_0^\infty g(x)=\int_0^11 dx+\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^{2}}dx$$
I have omitted the modulus on $x^{2}$ because I'm integrating only for positive values of $x$. The result is$$1+\biggl[-\frac{1}{x}\biggl]_1^\infty=1-(-0-(-1))=1-(1)=1-1=0$$
Is this the correct answer to the problem? I think that the result $0$ is probably ok. Thank you.

Comment: Review your computation: $\int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx=2$. The correct answer would be: By the LDC theorem, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty a_n(x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n(x)\,dx=?$$

Comment: Thank you! Sure, I have miss a sign. So, instead of $?$ I would write: $=\int_0^\infty g(x)dx=2$.
Last question: why we use $n=2$ (instead of any other values of $n$) to represent the function for larger $x$? Thank you for your patient and clear answers.

Comment: No. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n(x)=0$, $?=0$. You don't care what the integral of $g$ is, as long as it is finite. You use $g$ as an integrable majorant of the $a_n$ to be able to apply the LDC theorem.

Comment: Ok, so I just integrate the $a_{x}$ function founded before. So, $a(x)$ is the pointwise congergence function for $a_{n}(x)$ and is equal to $1$ only if $x=0$. So I have integrate $\int_1^1 1dx=0$. Is it correct now? Thank you.

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_n(x):=(\sin(x)/x)^n$ for $n\geqslant 1$. For each $x>0$ we have $\sin(x)\leqslant x$ so
$$\frac{f_{n+1}(x)}{f_n(x)}=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\leqslant 1$$
This implies that $(f_n(x))$ is a nonincreasing sequence for each $x>0$. Second we have
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}<\infty$$
and in general for $n\geqslant 2$: 
$$\Big|\int^{\infty}_0\Big(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\Big)^n\,dx\Big|\leqslant \int^1_0\Big|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\Big|^n\,dx+\int^{\infty}_1\Big|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\Big|^n\,dx\\\leqslant\int^1_0\Big|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\Big|^n\,dx+\int^{\infty}_1\frac{1}{x^n}\,dx<\infty$$
Hence $(f_n)$ is integrable on $(0,\infty)$. Moreover $f_n$ converges to the function $f$ with $f(x)=\sin(1)$ for $x=1$ and $f(x)=0$ else. Clearly $f$ is integrable with integral $\int f\,dx=0$. By monotone convergence theorem follows:
$$\lim_n\int^{\infty}_0f_n(x)\,dx=\int^{\infty}_0\lim_nf_n(x)\,dx=\int^{\infty}_0f(x)\,dx=0$$

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply. So, I have:
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\\\sin(1),  & \text{if     $0 \le x \le 1$} \\
0, & \text{x>1}
\end{cases}$$
So, if I want to apply the Lebesgue Dominated convergence theorem i should choose $g(x)=f(x)$. Am I right? Thank you.

Comment: You have $f(1)=\sin(1)$ and $f(x)=0$ for all other $x$, this is the pointwise limit of the sequence $(f_n(x))$. $(f_n)$ is monotone and integrable (these are important) and so apply monotone convergence theorem.